# Kashida with XePersian and XB Series Font

Tags: fonts

I am using `xepersian` and *XB Niloofar* font to produce Farsi documents. When enabling `[Kashida]` option, although *XB Niloofar* has the kashida (U+0640) glyph, I get a fuzzy output. Any solution?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[Kashida]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Niloofar}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{XB Niloofar}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=0.9]{Junicode}

\begin{document}
سلام، من هر روز به مدرسه می‌روم. 
بایستی به قدری بنویسم که تراز کردن 
اتفاق بیفتد و از کشیده استفاده شود. 
این کشــــــــیــــــــــده است؟
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XePersian seems to be inserting a horizontal rule not the kashida glyph regardless of the presence or absence of kashida in the font used (that what I see from the code).

Rules are rendered slightly differently from actual glyphs, which results in the fuzziness you see.

Comment: This option works fine with "Adobe Arabic" or "Scheherazade" fonts. Check [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian/xepersian.pdf).

Comment: I'd say the documentation is wrong, or I didn't understand it, since I tested with several fonts including Adobe Arabic and Scheherazade, and a rule is always used. With Adobe Arabic it is even more broken as there are wide gaps around the inserted rule.

Comment: @MohammadHedayati Link is broken. (Time does that to everything.)