# The command \KashidaXBFixOn does not work properly in xepersian

Tags: xepersian

Consider the following MWE:

```
% File: test-kashida.tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Kashida]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=4.5]{XB Kayhan} 
\def\SampleText{راهی جایی تابی چاپی چاهی تلاشهایی شتابهایی تابی چاپی راهی تلاشهــایی که کتابهایی که کلاههایی که}
\begin{document}
\KashidaOff \SampleText \lr{\Huge(Kashida Off)}

\KashidaOn \SampleText \lr{\Huge(Kashida On)}
\end{document}
```

The output of the above example is:
[image]
Even after the command \KashidaXBFixOn is added to the document, the dots below ‏"بی", "یی", "پی"‏ and so on, still seems to be displaced.

How can one fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of HM Series fonts has resolved the issue in his new package 'xepersian-hm' located at http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian-hm. More information is at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xepersian-hm.

The README.txt file of the package says:

Kashida feature in xepersian has problem with some fonts such as HM Series
fonts available at 'https://dma8hm1334.bitbucket.io' and XB Series fonts
available at 'http://wiki.irmug.com/index.php/X_Series_2'. The `xepersian-hm'
package fixes this problem.

Consider the following example which uses xepersian-hm:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% \usepackage[Kashida=off,RTLdocument=on]{xepersian}  % Load xepersian with a few options
\usepackage[Kashida,kashidastretch=0.14 em plus 0.5 em]{xepersian-hm}    % Succeeds
% \usepackage[Kashida,kashidastretch=noskip]{xepersian-hm}               % Succeeds
% \usepackage[Kashida,kashidastretch=default]{xepersian-hm}              % Succeeds
% \usepackage[Kashida,kashidastretch=kayhan]{xepersian-hm}               % Succeeds
% \usepackage[Kashida,kashidastretch=khorramshahr]{xepersian-hm}         % Succeeds
% \settextfont[Scale=4.5,Colour=darkgray]{XB XKayhan}
% \setlatintextfont[Scale=2.5,Colour=teal]{XB XKayhan}
\settextfont[Scale=4.5,Colour=darkgray]{HM XKayhan}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=2.5,Colour=teal]{HM XKayhan}
\def\SampleText{راهی جایی تابی چاپی چاههی تلاشهایی شتابهایی تابی چاپی راهی تلاشهــایی که کتابهایی که کلاههایی که}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\color{red}
\SampleText  \\ \lr{(compiled with: xepersian-hm)~}
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]
However, the output of the above example using xepersian is:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Write option `KashidaXBFix=on` in **xepersian** package.

\usepackage[Kashida=on,KashidaXBFix=on]{xepersian}

see this [link1](http://qa.parsilatex.com/13394), [link2](http://qa.parsilatex.com/19471) , [link3](http://qa.parsilatex.com/28344)

Please see this [questions](http://qa.parsilatex.com/34231)

Edit:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Kashida,KashidaXBFix=on]{xepersian}

\settextfont[Scale=4.5]{XB Niloofar} 
\def\SampleText{راهی جایی تابی چاپی چاهی تلاشهایی شتابهایی تابی چاپی راهی تلاشهــایی که کتابهایی که کلاههایی که}
\begin{document}
\KashidaOff \SampleText \lr{\Huge(Kashida Off)}

\KashidaOn \SampleText \lr{\Huge(Kashida On)}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

output: Font **IRXLotus**

[image]

**Edit**: 2020-03-21 see [link](http://qa.parsilatex.com/34569)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[Kashida=on,KashidaXBFix=on]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=4.5]{XB Kayhan} 


\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\yclass
\newXeTeXintercharclass\bypclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\ی \yclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\ب \bypclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\پ \bypclass
\XeTeXinterchartoks \bypclass \yclass = {}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \yclass \yclass = {}


\def\SampleText{راهی جایی تابی چاپی چاهی تلاشهایی شتابهایی تابی چاپی راهی تلاشهــایی که کتابهایی که کلاههایی که}
\begin{document}
\KashidaOff \SampleText \lr{\Huge(Kashida Off)}

\KashidaOn \SampleText \lr{\Huge(Kashida On)}
\end{document}
```

output

[image]

Comment: Probably the font problem. see [questions](http://qa.parsilatex.com/34231)

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same, since the methods are the same. Would you please test your answer.

Comment: @Tisha Shusho , See edit and link2.

Comment: I saw the links you mentioned in your answer. The only thing that I understood was that the kashida feature in xepersian works fine with some fonts but not with the others. So, it would be gratefully appreciated if you kindly briefly explain why kashida does not work fine with some fonts such as XB Kayahan, so that I can seek a solution. BTW, you have changed the font XB Kayhan to something else, like "XB Niloofar" in your answer. My question was "How can one fix the problem with XB Kayhan?". However, please note that kashida feature does not work properly with "XB Niloofar Italic" either.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38196/kashida-with-xepersian-and-xb-series-font

Comment: @M.Ahmadi, Your code (Edit: 2020-03-21) is not a solution to the problem because it prevents TeX from applying kashida to combinations of characters which cause the problem. In fact, you have disabled kashida feature for some combinations of characters. Please compare the output of your code with that of xepersian-hm below.

Answer (score 1):

Closer inspection shows the need for a fix:

[image: fix needed]

Without fix:

[image: without fix]

With fix:

[image: with fix]

I don't know enough for certain, but it looks as if use of the stretching-rule fix might need a further, fine-tuning, fix in some contexts (since different arrangements produce different stretches).

red = the font

non-red = presumably, the rule used to emulate stretching

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[Kashida=on,KashidaXBFix=on]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=4.5,Colour=red]{XB Kayhan} 
\def\SampleText{راهی جایی تابی چاپی چاهی تلاشهایی شتابهایی تابی چاپی راهی تلاشهــایی که کتابهایی که کلاههایی که}
\begin{document}\color{blue}
\KashidaOff \SampleText \lr{\Huge(Kashida Off)}

\KashidaOn \SampleText \lr{\Huge(Kashida On)}
\end{document}
```